# Spot and Forward rates - arbitrage?

Tags: forward-rate, spot-rate

Working on a problem to devise an arbitrage strategy. 1 year sport rate is 5% and 3 year spot rate is 5.5%, 1x3 Forward rate is 5.6%.
I calculated the 2 year spot rate as 5.75%

```
(1+0.055)^3 = (1+0.05)(1+S)^2 implies S = 5.75%
```

Using these spot rates, the actual 1x3 forward rate should be 11.83%

```
((1+S3)^3/(1+S1)) - 1 implies 11.83%, S3 is 3 year spot and S1 is 1 year spot
```

I can borrow $1 today, I will owe 1.05 in 1 year, I will enter into a 2 year forward and pay 5.6% and at the end of 3 years, I will owe 1.056. At the same time, at the end of year 1, I will lend a dollar at the current prevailing market rate of 5.75% and earn 1.1742 at the end of 3 years. This makes me a profit of 1.1742 - 1.056.

Am I on the right track ? Any feedback is much appreciated.

Yosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the implied forward rate (5.75%) is higher than the actual one (5.6%), the strategy should involve borrowing at the actual forward rate and investing at the implied one.

In what follows, I show the steps that you should take at the beginning/end of each year to exploit the arbitrage opportunity, along with the cash flows.

**t = 0:**

- Borrow X\$ for 1 year at 5.0%: +X\$
- Invest X\$ for 3 years at 5.5%: -X\$
- Enter into the forward contract to borrow X$(1+5%) 1 year from now for 2 years: 0\$

*Net cash flow: 0$*

**t = 1 (i.e. end of 1st year):**

- Borrow using the forward contract: +X\$(1+5%)
- Repay the loan: -X\$(1+5%)

*Net cash flow: 0\$*

**t = 3 (i.e. end of 3rd year):**

- Repay the forward contact: -X\$(1+5%)(1+5.6%)^2
- Gain from the investment: +X\$(1+5.5%)^3

*Net cash flow: X\$(0.00334857)*

**Additional comments:**

- I did not specify a monetary amount X\$, because in theory you would want to make this trade as big as possible, since it implies no investment (so you are not constrained by your capital) and no risk.

Comment: Perfectly clear! Thank you.